# Send key to OpenSSL via CLI

Tags: shell, openssl, rsa, command-line-interface

How can I send the RSA-key to `openssl rsautl` without putting it in a file first.

What I would like to do:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey "MII3f....324=="
```

instead of

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -inkey privateKey.pem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's impossible. The docs don't show any arguments that would allow this.

I guess I'll have to write a C++ wrapper.